# Too many arguments when using tuples to assign array values via map

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary, tuples

I'm using a tuple within a map to help me assign values in an array, but I'm getting "too many arguments for method update"

```
val a = Map((1,1) -> "alex", (2,2) -> "Jade")
val boardRep = Array.ofDim[String](3, 3)
a foreach { 
  case (key, value) => {
    boardRep((key._1), (key._2)) = value
  }
}
```

This should come out to an array with "alex" in the (1,1) spot and "Jade" in the (2,2) spot. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scala, creating an array of more than 1 dimension means creating Arrays inside Arrays:

```
scala> val boardRep = Array.ofDim[String](3, 3)
boardRep: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(null, null, null), Array(null, null, null), Array(null, null, null))
```

So to modify the cell `(1, 1)`, you'll have to modify in cell 1 of the main array (`boardRep(1)`: `Array(null, null, null)`), the cell 1 of this sub-array (`boardRep(1)(1)`)

```
a foreach {
  case (key, value) =>
    // boardRep((key._1), (key._2)) = value
    boardRep(key._1)(key._2) = value
}
```

which then gives:

```
Array(Array(null, null, null), Array(null, alex, null), Array(null, null, Jade))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arr(key1)(key2)` to access into a 2 dimensional array:

```
@ a foreach {
    case (key, value) => {
      boardRep(key._1)(key._2) = value
    }
  }


@ boardRep
res8: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(null, null, null), Array(null, "alex", null), Array(null, null, "Jade"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.tabulate` it is possible to create an array and populate (some) cells by applying a given function; in this case

```
Array.tabulate(3,3){ (i, j) => a.getOrElse((i,j), null) }
```

delivers

```
Array(Array(null, null, null), Array(null, alex, null), Array(null, null, Jade))
```